# What is the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n!)}{n!} x^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n!)}{n!} x^n$$

I found a question like this and there are four options

1. $R\geq 1$
2. $R\geq 2*\pi$
3. $R\leq 4*\pi$
4. $R\leq \pi$

where $R$ denotes radius of convergence.

I've tried hard but cant get it how to show in equality. 
Also there is question in my mind that among four options if the series is not converge at the end point can we discard that option. 
I'm not sure abut this since we know if anywhere "$<$" holds we can say "$\leq$" holds, but the converse isn't not true.

Comment: Is there any reason why $a_0$ is given a specific different value than the $\sin 1$ it would normally have been?

Comment: The presence of $\pi$ in the options makes it dubious that you correctly reproduced the question.

Comment: @Daoust sir cant get you sir

Answer (score 2):

Since $|a_n|\le\frac1{n!}$ it follows that the radius of convergence is $\infty$, just as is the case  for $\exp(x)$.

Comment: sir why radius of convergence is ∞?

Comment: The sum can be bounded by $$-e^x-1\lt\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_nx^n \lt e^x-1$$

Comment: @Peter sir then what is the radius of convergence?

Comment: $R=\infty$ - if the sum can be bounded for all $x$ then it must converge for all $x$.